# Using node.js http proxy inside a Redis callback

Tags: node.js, redis, http-proxy

Considering this incomplete snippet:

```
var util = require('util'),
    nconf = require('nconf'),

    http = require('http'),
    httpProxy = require('http-proxy'),

    express = require('express'),
    repoServer = express.createServer(),

    redis = require('redis'),
    redisClient = redis.createClient();

// (...)

var proxy = new httpProxy.RoutingProxy();
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  console.log("URL", req.url);
  if (req.url) {
    var token = req.url.split("/")[1];

    // if I leave this code here it works fine
    // var target = { host: 'local-01', port: 8024 }
    // proxy.proxyRequest(req, res, target);

    // now I need to retrieve some routing information
    // from redis, so I query redis here
    redisClient.get(token, function (err, reply) {
      // if I leave this code here the request hangs
      var target = { host: 'local-01', port: 8024 }
      proxy.proxyRequest(req, res, target);
    });
  }
}).listen(routerInfo.port, routerInfo.address);
```

Why is it that when I call the `proxyRequest` outside de redis client `get` callback it works , but when I move the call inside the callback it fails and the HTTP request just hangs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

request is stream, maybe you want to buffer

see: https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy/blob/master/examples/http/latent-proxy.js

Comment: I ended up figuring this out almost at the same time you answered this. Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand how to solve this use case, please can you explain ?